# How to change Wordpress URL when it's already in subdirectory of Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, wordpress

We are building a site on Magento 2 EE . The site will be a multi-site and each site will have its own Wordpress. We integrated Wordpress using a plugin, it sits in the subdirectory of Magento 2.

We are using Wordpress for blog, support, about us - and other content, we're using native Magento features for PIM.

We were told that ***www.example.com/intl*/** belongs to Magento, so we can't change that.

So our vendor offered to use ***www.example.com/wp/post123*** but what we actually want is: ***www.example.com/support/testcontact*** or ***www.example.com/blog/blogpost1***

Does anyone have a solution for this and is it possible to have a dynamic URL for Wordpress so it doesn't have to be hardcoded? We're running on NginX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Fishpig to combine the 2 platforms together, if you are then you can purchase the Root module for it which allows you to take off /wp/ from the url and replace it with what ever you want you can find it at https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/root/

If your using a different plugin if you could advise which one this would make more easier to advise on a solution

Comment: Hello Dave, no, we haven't used that. Our vendor decided to use another plugin which is this one:  https://modernmodules.com/plugins/magento-2-wordpress-integration-plugin/ 

Thank you!

Comment: Without reviewing the code its a bit impossible to see a possible work around i would suggest contacting the module creator and asking if they can implement this or use fishpig as can be setup in 5 minutes

Comment: Dave, so just to be clear,  with Fishpig this issue above should not occur if we also add the Root add on, correct? If so we'll have it changed.

Comment: With fishpig it allows you to add wordpress as both a blog and cms pages also with the rooting extension it allows you to have custom urls so yoursite.com/wp/ is changed to yousite.com/whateveryouwant also cms pages will go from yoursite.com/wp/about-us to just yoursite.com/about-us which as far as i can see from your original post